# Python program to convert a list to string

Tags: python

I have a list
`list = ["Num1","Num2","Num3"]`
how can I convert list to string like:
`Num1 => avg(Num1) as ABC`
I found function join but I can't convert

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. The expected output doesn't contain the list, it only shows the first item.  You could get that output with a format string: `f"{list[0]} => avg({list[0]}) as ABC"` but it seems unlikely that this would be what you are really looking for.  BTW you should not used a reserved word (list) as a variable name.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!This: `Num1 => avg(Num1) as ABC` does not explain what you want to achieve. What is `avg` and what does `as` mean? It looks like you want to write an expression parser. If so, that may be a bit ambitious for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `join()` method takes in an iterable as an argument (in you case, the list), and joins it with the string that you called it on (i.e., an empty string or a space). So in your case, you can use:

```
' '.join(list) # 'Num1 Num2 Num3'
```

Also, `list` is a bad variable name since it eclipses the built in function `list()`.

Answer (score -1):

```
list_sum = 0
for entry in list:
      list_sum += int(entry)
list_average = list_sum / len(list)
```

Something like that should work

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).